# Only half of my apartment electric radiators come on

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heating, central-heating, radiator

I hope I am in the right to place to ask for help.

I am in the UK, have a small apartment with 4 radiators. They look like they are electric (no pipes running to them). This is a relatively new build of 2-3 years.

There are 2 thermostats, one in bedroom and one in living room. Assuming they each control 2 radiators. I have attached photos.

I am trying to diagnose why 2-3 of the 4 radiators do not turn on. 2 of the 4 radiators have a turn knob with numbers and 2 just have a turn knob. The radiator that works has a numbered turn knob. I have turned them all the way towards the "+" and the numbered ones to "4". This radiator "fully works" and gets very hot. The second radiator (bedroom) gets only slightly hot. The final 2 radiators are stone cold.

We have never turned the heating on so far so wondering if something needs to be switched on or enabled. We have scheduled a professional to come on Monday to fix it but just wondering if there is anything obvious I can try over the weekend.

There is a fuse in the fuse box labelled "Central Heating" and is up a long with all the other fuses in the box.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what are the pipe-looking things if not pipes?

Answer (score 2):

The room thermostat is working !

The central heating is working !

2 radiators remain cold ?

Problem - Air in the pipes

Solution-- vent the pipes/ radiators

FYI--not electric radiators